# Number of sub-rectangle of size x,y which cover a cell p,q in a rectangle of size n*m

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have a rectangle of size n*m (Where n is a number of rows and m is the number of columns) which is divided into of size 1*1.

I want to calculate the number of the sub-rectangle of size P*Q which contains the cell (x,y) in them.

For example a rectangle of size 3*3 where I need to find all sub-rectangle of size 2*2 which contains the cell (2,2). There will be total 4 such sub-rectangle will be there.
[image]
 I have tried to solve them by breaking into horizontal and vertical cells.
for Horizontal number of cells containing 
**x,y =min(1,x-P+1)-max(n,x+P-1)+1**
similarly for vertical cells and multiplying the result.But somehow bug is there in my approach i guess

Comment: Please post your attempted code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You only need the number of rectangles, or do you also need to enumerate them?

Comment: I have done the edit. I only need the number of sub-rectangle

Comment: What is the topmost leftmost subrectangle of the given size that contains your cell? What is the topmost rightmost one? What is the bottommost leftmost and bottommmost rightmost ones? Everything is between these four. This has zilch to do with programming by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectangle: `N * M`
Cell cover: `P,Q`
with Rectangle size: `X,Y`

Then horizontal move: `U = Min(Q+Y-1,M) - Max(Q-Y+1,1) + 1 - Y + 1`.

Vertical move: `V = Min(P+X-1,N) - Max(P-X+1,1) + 1 - X + 1` .

Then Answer: `U * V`

**Editorial:**

If you want to cover cell `(P,Q)` with rectangle size `X * Y` then you need to calculate how many distance you can cover from `Q` to `right side(M)` and `Q to left side(1)`. If this distance `i` then you can move rectangle  `U = i - Y + 1` horizontally.

Then you need to calculate how many distance you can cover from `P` to `down side(N)` and `P` to `up side(1)`. If this distance `j` then you can move rectangle `V = j - X + 1`.

So answer : `U * V`

**Example:**
Lets N = 5 , M = 5 and P = 3, Q = 3, X= 3 and Y = 3.

If you want to cover cell (3,3) then you can go right side max (3,5) position and left side max ( 3, 1) position. then how many move there is possible: `(3,1) -> (3, 3)`, `(3 , 2) -> (3, 4)` , `(3, 3) -> (3, 5)` . So max position move 5 - 1 + 1 -3 + 1.

Calculate same way for vertical move.

Comment: X,Y is not a new rectangle but a cell which should be there in new Rectangle formed of size P,Q

Comment: then reverse p,q x,y

Comment: i just give formula

Comment: in your question you wanted to cover cell(p,q) with size x*y rectangle. right?

Comment: actually reverse wanted to cover cell(x,y) of size p*q.Anyway i will reverse

Comment: i did one mistake. edited. check now

Comment: did you try with this formula?

Comment: yeah it seems working

Comment: can u please explain a little

Comment: ok. i add in answer.

Comment: i tried to explain. sry for bad english

Answer (score -1):

This code might help:

```
x_extent = max( min( [P, x+1, n-x, n-P+1] ), 0)
y_extent = max( min( [Q, y+1, m-y, m-Q+1] ), 0)
number_of_rectangles = x_extent * y_extent
```

Basically, the number of the rectangles will be `P * Q` for any point somewhere in the middle, considering `m` and `n` being relatively large. But if your point (x,y) is very close to the edge, you need to shave off a row or a column here and there.

(In the above -- PxQ is the covering rectangle, (x,y) point in the (m,n) lattice that should be covered)

Comment: now also it does not satisfy if n=3 m=3 ,p=2 q=2 x=2 and x=2.Answer should be 4 but from above it is coming as 1

Comment: @ivanR x=2, y=2 is a corner square in (3x3) matrix. how can it be 4 ?? in python, the indices into 3x3 matrix would be (0, 1, 2).

Comment: in pic i have started index from 1,1

Comment: @ivanR you should learn how to index lists and matrices in **python**, it's not basic or pascal or whatever

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments :( .But if user is giving input in diffrent format it needs to be handled in python code. You cant tell them I am using python so u start from 0

Comment: @ivanR nothing personal in my comments. Python/C/C++ are zero-based languages. if you get a different input, convert it right where you get it. otherwise you have to be ready for pain and suffering, "off-by-one" is a very common and very nasty kind of mistakes people make.